# Best way to push iOS notification after calculating result from its input received for a network call?

Tags: ios, swift, google-api, cron, server-side

I'm working on something where my iOS app will give 2 input parameters to some server side setup. The server side will periodically run a google API network call and get its result response X. When this X is the right answer, I want the server side to send my iOS app a push notification. This needs to happen for every app user individually.

I know the iOS coding part, and also know how to setup a iOS push notification.

But what’s the best way to setup this **server side** code? Are there some free cloud instances that I could use?

I’ve looked into Firebase and Google Cloud console that I can combine with a cron job to make regular network calls, but they seem to have a fair bit of complexity involved (especially since it’ll be inputs from per app install so it'll become one cron job per app install).

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.

for future visitors, i’m writing how i achieved it -

the client sends inputs to the firebase DB, and a firebase cloud function scheduler periodically reads those values to calculate output from google api call. when the output is right, the firebase cloud function sends notification to the client